# How to I get igraph to ignore blank cells?

Tags: r, graph, neural-network, igraph

So I have this dataframe that we will call test_a2. I want to use igraph to create a network map.

```
Col 1      Col 2     Col 3    Col 4

 Table A | Table B | Table C | 

 Table Z | Table A | Table C | Table Y

 Table K | Table L | Table M | Table B

 Table J | Table H |
```

I am currently using the following code to map multiple columns

```
plot(graph.data.frame(rbindlist(lapply(seq(ncol(test_a2)-1), function(i) test_a2[i:(i+1)]))))
```

This give me a graph with nodes and edges. However,  where there is an empty space which it creates a node for and create unnecessary connection. Anyway to have it ignore this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
test_a2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("A","Z","K","J"),
                      col2 = c("B","A","L","H"),
                      col3 = c("C","C","M",""),
                      col3 = c("","Y","B",""), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test_a2[test_a2 ==""] <- NA

test_a3 <- na.omit(rbindlist(lapply(seq(ncol(test_a2)-1), function(i) test_a2[i:(i+1)])))
plot(graph.data.frame(test_a3))][1]][1]
```

[image: Graph]

One note about this approach: the graph will not contain vertices that are not connected with anything else but "empty" cells. If you need to include them you can add them afterwards.

Comment: For some reason the code is not working. It is saying that tha the \ is unexpected. I am trying to debug it but my lack of R skills is making that difficult. Any suggestions?

Comment: I actually just asked one of my peers and we got rid of the back slashes and made another edit and it turned out to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right - this was a typo while I was copying-pasting. I fixed it. Thank you.